# syntax error while trying to INSERT INTO table with postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error

Here's the link to my table:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/07f75

Here is my code, but I am getting syntax errors. I've played with a few things, like adding '' around my varchar data types, even changed the text, but am getting this error currently: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "moon’" Position: 76`

The syntax error has changed since I changed the text, as well as the position, but the type of error has stayed the same. I thought I understood how to insert data into the table but I am at a loss!

```
CREATE TABLE spacecrafts (
    id integer, 
    name varchar(15),   
    launched integer, 
    country varchar(10),
    mission text, 
    orbitingbody varchar(10), 
    operating varchar(1), 
    milesfromearth integer
); 

INSERT INTO spacecrafts
    VALUES 
    (1, ‘rocketeer1’, 2018, ‘USA’, ‘reach moon’, ‘mars’, ‘y’, 100000),
    (2, ‘rocketer2’, 2015, ‘Brazil’, ‘reach moon’, ‘Jupiter’, ’n’, 303230),
    (3, ‘rocketship’, 2014, ‘Germany’, ‘reach Jupiter’, ’n’, 67939380);
```

Comment: `operating varchar(1)` Note: Postgres has a native boolean type, save yourself the future headache and don't store booleans as strings.

Comment: Use a proper quote character.  `'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to insert string data use `'` instead of `’`

```
CREATE TABLE spacecrafts (
    id integer, 
    name varchar(15),   
    launched integer, 
    country varchar(10),
    mission text, 
    orbitingbody varchar(10), 
    operating varchar(1), 
    milesfromearth integer
); 

INSERT INTO spacecrafts VALUES  
    (1, 'rocketeer1', 2018, 'USA', 'reach moon', 'mars', 'y', 100000),
    (2, 'rocketer2', 2015, 'Brazil', 'reach moon', 'Jupiter', 'n', 303230),
    (3, 'rocketship', 2014, 'Germany', 'reach Jupiter','test', 'n', 67939380);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/89787/1)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple errors. I changed your tick marks `'` (key in top left) to a quote ' (key next to enter). Those change with cut & paste sometimes so you may not have done that directly.

The other change is on your third entry you don't have an orbitingbody entry.

```
INSERT INTO spacecrafts 
VALUES (1, 'test', 2018, 'usa', 'reach moon', 'mars', 'y', 100000),
(2, 'rocketer2', 2015, 'Brazil', 'reach moon', 'Jupiter', 'n', 303230),
(3, 'rocketship', 2014, 'Germany', 'reach Jupiter', 'Venus', 'n', 67939380);
```

Notice I added 'Venus' to the third entry.